why bat can not enter edit mode?
when I run command "sudo bat a.sh" then enter v, I can not enter edit mode as help document described. my env variable is
echo $VISUAL
nano -m -$
echo $EDITOR
nano -m -$
the status bar show the message as following:
can not edit standard input (press enter)
please help to see this problem, thanks a lot
